# Expression in a report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that shows the way people have contacted our business - phone, email etc. When people run the report, they choose the contact method via a drop down parameter. They can select one / many / all contact methods.

I have added a chart to my report that shows top 10s by contact method - basically why did people contact us.

In order to be reasonably dynamic, I have added this expression to the title of the chart:

```
="Top 10 contact reasons:" + " " + Parameters!Contact.Value(0)
```

This works fine when one contact method is chosen, but not more than one.

Ideally I'd like the title to say, if someone has chosen more than one contact method (say phone and email):

"Top 10 contact reasons: phone and email"

At the moment it just shows one value, because my expression isn't dynamic enough to include more than one choice.

If anyone has any suggestions to improve my expression, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

="Top 10 contact reasons:" + " " + join(Parameters!Contact.Value,",")